# Fork rate range in terms of network security

Tags: blockchain, block, blockchain-fork, block-size-increase, block-interval

I am really new to bitcoin and am trying to understand the basics. Fork rate/Orphan rate is a measure of network security.

[image]

The higher the fork rate, the more compromised the system. Also fork rate is directly proportional to block size and inversely proportional to block interval time.

My question is what range is considered safe for fork rate in terms of network security?

Comment: Where did that come from? That's not a common definition.

Comment: I am a student at university and this was the definition provided by my professor